# Passing a rotation value to css

Tags: jquery, css

I have a variable called value in my js that gets updated based on the scrollbars percent. my value is between 0 - 360. I want a way to update the below css values. Is there a way I can group them together in an object and pass the value to them. For example when using opacity I can do something like this.

```
function updateCSS(target, value){
 var cssObj = {};
 cssObj["opacity"] = value;
 target.css(cssObj);
}
```

I need a way to be able to update all the prefix rotate property with my value number. Any good ideas how I could do this.

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(value);  /* Safari 3.1+, Chrome 
     -moz-transform: rotate(value);  /* Firefox 3.5-15 
      -ms-transform: rotate(value);  /* IE9+ 
       -o-transform: rotate(value);  /* Opera 10.5-12.00 
          transform: rotate(value);  /* Firefox 16+, Opera 12.50+
```

Comment: Why do you need to update all of them? Use modernizr to detect what value is used in the current browser and update it, others will be ignored anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `.css()` method, and also you forgot to include `deg`:

```
function updateCSS(target, value){
    target.css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+value+'deg)',
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+value+'deg)',
        '-ms-transform': 'rotate('+value+'deg)',
        '-o-transform': 'rotate('+value+'deg)',
        'transform': 'rotate('+value+'deg)'
    });
}
```

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/XKyEz/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `style` object to change CSS properties:

```
var style = element.style;
style.WebkitTransform =
    style.MozTransform =
    style.msTransform =
    style.OTransform =
    style.transform = 'rotate(' + angle + ')';
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS is not a programming language. It does not support variables. You need to use JavaScript to do this.

`$(target).attr('-webkit-transform', 'rotate('+value+')');` ....etc

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jquery very simply:

```
$(target).css('opacity',value);
```